# Can't satisfy warning when linking against a dylib

Tags: ios, swift, warnings, dylib, pure-layout

I'm learning how to integrate a `Today Extension` for my application, but `Xcode` keeps throwing me the following warning:

```
linking against a dylib which is not safe for use in application extensions:
```

I'm using [PureLayout](https://github.com/PureLayout/PureLayout) to manage `Auto Layout` within my extension.

In addition to setting "Require Only App-Extension-Safe API" to true, I also did the following from PureLayout's [documentation](https://github.com/PureLayout/PureLayout/wiki/App-Extensions#if-youve-integrated-the-source-code-directly-into-your-project) .

Answer (score 0):

What ever your FrameWork is ,you need to have Separate Framework for extensions. The Framework you've added might be for Normal Targets. There isn't any issue with it. Since your intention is Learning ,Just set the flag  "Require Only App-Extension-Safe API" to **NO**,the warning will be vanished. Suppose you are going to put in App Store ,Set the same as **YES**,warning will comes again and the AppStore wants to see it. Unless you've to link Framework solely created for extensions